# What's wrong with this Nautilus script?

Tags: scripting, nautilus, avconv

I'm trying to write a simple Nautilus script that lets me select a media file, right-click to get Nautilus script menu, and convert it into an mp3 using avconv

```
name=$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS
name2="${name%.*}.mp3"

d=`gdialog --title "Convert" --msgbox " $name \n $name2" 200 450`
system (@d)

avconv -i "$name" "$name2"
```

The gdialog pops up ... and tells me that I'm generating appropriate names (including the paths). But but no actual conversion takes place.

Comment: Are you trying to mix `perl` and shell  commands ? What if you remove lines 4 and 5 from your script (and add a shebang...) ?

Comment: No. These are all shell, I believe. The first four lines DO run. It just looks like the fifth doesn't. But the fifth runs fine when I type it on the command line.

Comment: You "believe" ? No man, `system (@d)` is _not_ shell, it's `perl`... So my suggestion was to remove that line and the previous one and leave only the assignments and the `avconv` one. Also, afaik `avconv` works with one input file so make sure you select just one file.  And start `nautilus` from terminal when testing this stuff, that way you can see more error messages (also check your session log, most likely you'll find some messages related to your script).

Comment: Ah ... I see what you mean ... experimenting